# qt mousemoveEvent (involved with qss)

Tags: qt, qt4, onmousemove

I have a widget class 'BlockWidget' subclass of QLabel, in the ctor I set its qss qss_1, and I want animated effect that when the mouse move on it, it will change its background-color, so I set its qss qss_2, but it seems not working... My code like this:

```
BlockWidget::BlockWidget(const QString &objname)
{
    this->setObjectName(objname);
    setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    setStyleSheet(tr("BlockWidget#%1{color:white; background-color: gray; font-size:18px;"
                 "font-family:'Consolas';}").arg(objectName()));
}

void BlockWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    setStyleSheet(tr("BlockWidget#%1{color:white; background-color: blue; font-size:18px;"
                 "font-family:'Consolas';}").arg(objectName()));
    repaint();
}
```

And I have a mainwindow, I instantiated 81 instances of BlockWidget. when my mouse move to one of them, nothing happened. but if I click on it some times, it do change its qss style(its background turns blue)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the documentation, mouse move events are only sent when you click, drag or release the buttons, if mouse tracking isn't enabled for the widget.

You can detect the mouse entering and leaving the labels by redefining `QWidget::enterEvent` and `QWidget::leaveEvent` in your `BlockWidget` class.

Or you can simply use the `:hover` QSS pseudo-state without having to redefine any mouse related function:

```
setStyleSheet("BlockWidget {"
              "    color:white;"
              "    background-color: gray;" 
              "    font-size:18px;"
              "    font-family:'Consolas';"
              "}"
              "BlockWidget:hover {"
              "    background-color: blue;" 
              "}");
```

**PS:**

- According to Qt style sheet documentation, `QLabel` doesn't support the `:hover` pseudo-state, however changing the background or the borders seems to be working fine.
- Since your `BlockWidget` widgets don't have themselves `BlockWidget` children, and because you set the stylesheet individually to all of them, it should be safe to omit the object name from the QSS selector.

Comment: Your enterEvent and leaveEvent solution actually solves the "detect hover event" problem that has never had a simple answer. My hat to you!

Answer (score 1):

You must enable mouse tracking for your widget http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop